# Angular @Hostbinding does not work

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-hostbinding

i've similar problem with @Hostbinding like other questions, but i could not solve that.

My template:

```
<main class="my_active">


    <user myDirective="'false'">
    </user>
</main>
```

And my directive

```
@Directive({
    selector:'[myDirective]'
})

export class MyDerective {


    @HostBinding('class.img')
    isMyCirclePic:boolean;

    @HostListener('mouseover')
    onMouseEnter(){
        console.log('VALUE BEFORE:', this.isMyCirclePic);
        console.log('MAUS ENTER');
        this.isMyCirclePic=true;
        console.log('VALUE AFTER:', this.isMyCirclePic);

    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave')
    onMouseLeave(){
        console.log('VALUE BEFORE:', this.isMyCirclePic);
        console.log('MAUS LEAVE');
        this.isMyCirclePic=false;
        console.log('VALUE AFTER:', this.isMyCirclePic);
    }
}
```

1. Problem is, that my  isMyCirclePic is undefined for the first time. After that it will be set true of false. I use same template several times, and when i click on other template (from same kind of template), so isMyCirclePic undefined also.
2. I'am changing true or false within events, but it will no be rendered. My 'class.img'-picture stays everytime on the same value.

**UPDATE**

I've tried out solution with @Input @HostBinding.

```
<main class="my_active">
    <user 
        myDerective
        [myColor]="font_color">
    </user>
</main>
```

And my myColor-Direktive:

```
@Directive({
    selector:'[myColor]'
})
export class MyColor {

    @HostBinding('style.color')
    font_color:string;

    @Input()
    set myColor(color:string) {
        this.font_color = color;
        console.log('COLOR VALUE SET:', this.font_color);
    }

    get myColor():string{
        console.log('COLOR VALUE GET:', this.font_color);
        return this.font_color;
    }
}
```

But it still not working. I can see, that the value will be passed by @Input-param. I can see, that set-function will be called. But i can't see, that get-function will be called, what i've expected. So i see no changes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use @Input() @HostBinding

```
@Directive({
    selector:'[myDirective]'
})

export class MyDerective {
   @Input() @HostBinding('class.img') isMyCirclePic:boolean;

    @HostListener('mouseover')
    onMouseEnter(){
        console.log('VALUE BEFORE:', this.isMyCirclePic);
        console.log('MAUS ENTER');
        this.isMyCirclePic=true;
        console.log('VALUE AFTER:', this.isMyCirclePic);

    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave')
    onMouseLeave(){
        console.log('VALUE BEFORE:', this.isMyCirclePic);
        console.log('MAUS LEAVE');
        this.isMyCirclePic=false;
        console.log('VALUE AFTER:', this.isMyCirclePic);
    }
}
```

bind it in tmeplate

```
 <div myDirective [isMyCirclePic]="false">
             myDirective
</div>
```

Comment: Thx. thats nice solution, but i should be possible to do that without @input. At least i could use that.

Comment: You can reuse name of directive and its name, so html will look like [myDirective]='false' and @Input ... myDirective

Comment: That is nice work around, but it should works. 
For example i can see here by description of @Hostbinding, thats have to work: 
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/custom-directives/hostlistener-and-hostbinding/